# Button click hanlder in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to bind an on click action, to a button i have in my view. As i'm trying to followe the MVVM guidelines, i want my `ButtonAddBook` method, in the `ViewModel`, but with my button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="SurnamaeBox" Content="Add book" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="646,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="2" Click="ButtonAddBook"/>
```

Nothing really happens when i click the button. I tried also `Click="{Binding ButtonAddBook}"` and that just makes the program crash with exception:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.
```

So what is the workaround, for having button methods in ViewModel, instead of View?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: usually in wpf, you would use an ICommand (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=net-6.0) and bind to Button.Command to handle the click. if you are using uwp/winui, you can also directly bind to your method with x:bind (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Add a RelayCommand class to your viewmodel which inherites from ICommand like

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then also add

```
private ICommand _buttonAddBook;

public ICommand ButtonAddBook
{
    get
    {
        if (_buttonAddBook == null)
            _buttonAddBook = new RelayCommand(param => DoStuff(), param => CanDoStuff());

        return _buttonAddBook;
    }
}
```

Where `DoStuff()` will be the method to be executed by calling the `Command="{Binding ButtonAddBook}"` not `Click="{Binding ButtonAddBook}"` and in `CanDoStuff()` you can set the validation for when you can run the `DoStuff()`.